# Electron cannot find module mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, module

So i've been creating a desktop application using electron. The problem is that when I run my application using npm it doesn't show any error about a missing module but when i package it and run it this error shows
[image]

I'm sure that i've install mysql module using npm install -g mysql and npm install mysql in the project directory. It's all working fine when i run the unpacked version of the application

Comment: Does it works in exe? I'm also pondering about create a exe application but facing issue that which database I chose? As I want to go offline as it don't required internet to run

Comment: Can you please share how could you do this? I don't want to tell my customer to install MySQL and all. It must be bind with my exe. They just have to install exe and it must be ready to us.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed mysql if not please install mysql  `npm install mysql --save-dev`

> Hi I also ran in same error I tried everything possible but nothing seems to work , after several hit and trial I was able to fix it and in the end realize that it was all happening because of

1. When I installed MySQL module I never saved it (--save-dev)
2. And electron-packager was not able to locate it when I pack it because was not mention in package.json

A solution might locate mysql folder  in node_module folder and delete
then install it `npm install mysql --save-dev`

or manually 
add it under dependencies in package.json file

Comment: thanks for that. already solved this using the same procedure you did about 2 months ago.